# Jodatime trabajar solo con horas y minutos

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que tengo que sumar horas a partir de una hora establecida como:

> 00:00

este dato es un String a la que debo ir sumando horas y minutos relacionados con unos partes de trabajo.
Estoy usando `Jodatime` que creo que es más util que ir sumando yo las horas , minutos....
Lo que estoy haciendo es crear un objeto LocalDateTime al que quiero ir sumándole horas pero no consigo que se situé en un día en las 00:00 :

```
  LocalDateTime parteLocalHoraFinDt = new LocalDateTime();
        parteLocalHoraFinDt.withHourOfDay(0);
        parteLocalHoraFinDt.withMinuteOfHour(0);
        parteLocalHoraFinDt.withSecondOfMinute(0);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Alguna otra idea para ir sumando horas a un String "00:00" ?

Comment: Si el fondo rojo indica que es donde estás parado en la depuración, avanza 3 pasos/sentencias más antes de mirar el valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procura siempre que uses una biblioteca ver su [documentacion](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#withHourOfDay-int-)

Los metodos `with...` dicen en su documentacion que retornan una copia, no modifican el objeto original:

> Returns a copy of this datetime with the hour of day field updated.

Mas aun, la misma clase LocalDateTime dice que es inmutable:

> LocalDateTime is an unmodifiable datetime class representing a
>   datetime without a time zone.

Para usarla debes utilizar lo que retorna:

```
LocalDateTime parteLocalHoraFinDt = new LocalDateTime()
        .withHourOfDay(0)
        .withMinuteOfHour(0)
        .withSecondOfMinute(0);
```

Ese estilo de interfaz se conoce como [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: gracias Klaimmore, no se me da muy bien el ingles y no entendia bien la documentación

Comment: pero otra pregunta .... entonces luego no puedo hacer  parteLocalHoraFinDt.plusHours(5);

Comment: Si puedes, pero para que sea util el resultado de ese metodo debes asignarlo a tu variable: `parteLocalHoraFinDt = parteLocalHoraFinDt.plusHours(5);`